# Fill TextBlock within a Button with database records

Tags: c#, wpf

lets say i have 10 rows in my database table. I want to create 10 `Button`s and `TextBlock` inside `Button`s filled with data rows. I already create the 10 `Button`s and `TextBlock` inside it here is the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
        Button Btn = new Button();
            Style style = this.FindResource("MetroNewButton") as Style;
            Btn.Style = style;
            Btn.Width = 250;
            Btn.Height = 80;
            Btn.Name = "BtnCA" + i;
            Btn.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
            Btn.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            Btn.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;

             for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
               {
                        Grid GridContent = new Grid();
                GridContent.Width = 250;
                GridContent.Height = 80;

                TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
                txtBlock.Name = "txtBlock" + j;
                txtBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                txtBlock.FontSize = 14;
                txtBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                //txtBlock1.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
                txtBlock.Padding = new Thickness(10, 20, 0, 0);
                txtBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
                Grid.SetRow(txtBlock, 0);
                 GridContent.Children.Add(txtBlock);
                Btn.Content = GridContent;
               } 
  }
```

Okay and i have list carries data from database.I want to distribute data to text block, So how to put data in Text block ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, using ItemsControl with proper ItemTemplate would be better idea than creating all the controls in for loop. Just create a list of objects representing your data, bind it to ItemsCOntrol(ItemsSource={Binding your_path}), and set proper item template for grid. After that, put an ItemsControl inside a button. If i understood you right, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this `for` loop, you can create buttons using `XAML` and `MVVM binding`.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding btnList}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding  btn_NAME}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

Then fetch content from `db` and fill it into `btnList`.

To get more idea about `MVVM binding`, please go through [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ptmujeeb/wpf-mvvm-pattern-a-simple-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx).